# T-SQL (Transact-SQL): Two separate tables. Need the find the date that is >= in Table A based on a date in Table B

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

Two separate tables. Need the find the date that is >= in Table A based on a date in Table B. Only TransactionCode 59 in Table A should be considered.

From the example tables below my return in table B First_Tran_Date should be "01/22/2022." Table A contains over 35 million records with thousands of AccountNumber's and grows each day.

Need T-SQL to take Table B ChangeDate "01/21/2022" and find the first time Table A shows a TransactionDate on or after that date and only TransactionCode 59 counts. All other TransactionCode dates should not be evaluated for the return.

Table A:

```
AccountNumber     TransactionDate     TransactionCode
xxxx310           2/3/2022            40
xxxx310           1/19/2022           40
xxxx310           1/22/2022           59
xxxx310           1/10/2022           59
xxxx310           3/15/2022           40
xxxx310           1/25/2022           59
xxxx310           1/30/2022           40
xxxx310           1/31/2022           59
xxxx310           1/31/2022           62
xxxx310           3/8/2022            59
```

Table B:

```
Account     ChangeDate     First_Tran_Date     COUNT_OF_DAYS
xxxx310     01/21/2022     **RESULT NEEDED**   (Calculated First_Tran_Date - ChangeDate = COUNT_OF_DAYS)
```

I have tried the following without getting a correct result:

T-SQL example...

Created a VIEW…

```
WITH added_row_number AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY AccountNumber
            ORDER BY
                TransactionDate
        ) AS row_number
    FROM dbo.LoanTransactions
)
SELECT
    *
FROM added_row_number
WHERE row_number = 1
    AND TransactionDate >= '2022-03-01'
    AND TransactionCode IN ('59', '61', '70', '77', '82') Used a
```

SELECT
from that VIEW …

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT Account,
    Prod_CD,
    OldValue,
    NewValue,
    Acct_Open_DT,
    ChangeDate,
    LOSVIEW_All_Transactions_From_CORE1.TransactionDate AS First_Tran_Date,
    LastTransactionDate,
CASE
        WHEN Prod_CD IN ('L50', 'L51', 'L54', 'L77') THEN DATEDIFF(
            DAY,
            ChangeDate,
            LOSVIEW_All_Transactions_From_CORE1.TransactionDate
        )
        ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY, Acct_Open_DT, ChangeDate)
    END AS COUNT_OF_DAYS
FROM dbo.R_InsuranceCodeChanges
LEFT JOIN dbo.LOSVIEW_All_Transactions_From_CORE AS LOSVIEW_All_Transactions_From_CORE1
    ON dbo.R_InsuranceCodeChanges.Account = LOSVIEW_All_Transactions_From_CORE1.AccountNumber
WHERE
    dbo.R_InsuranceCodeChanges.ChangeDate >= '2022-01-01'
    AND dbo.R_InsuranceCodeChanges.NewValue <> '0'
```

Comment: Please sort out the formatting of your code. Its unreadable.

Comment: I strongly recommend better (and much less) use of whitespace and linebreaks; that code has so much wasted space. Also 3+ naming from columns is to be deprecated; don't use it. Alias your objects and then use those to qualify your columns.

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to look up two dates, and also calculate the number of days between them?

Those dates should be the first and last time a row with TransactionCode 59 appears, for a given account, and only including records on or after a given date?

So for the data in your example, the missing date should be 2022-01-22? Then the number of days would be 52 days?

For that I would use OUTER APPLY; which allows you to effectively run a query once for each input row...

```
SELECT
  *,
  DATEDIFF(DAY, table_a.MinTransactionDate, table_a.MaxTransactionDate)
FROM
  table_b
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT
    MIN(TransactionDate) AS MinTransactionDate,
    MAX(TransactionDate) AS MaxTransactionDate
  FROM
    table_a
  WHERE
        AccountNumber    = table_b.Account
    AND TransactionDate >= table_b.ChangeDate
    AND TransactionCode  = 59
)
  AS table_a
```

Comment: Basically I need to find the Account Number in both tables that match, then From table B use the ChangeDate find the next transaction => that date from table A. That said, I need to ignore any from Table A that do not have CODE 59. Sorry this is my first time posting and trying to get the language correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @troy Paraphrasing what I said doesn't really help. Was what I said correct or not? If not, please explain specifically what was not correct, using examples, by editing your question.

Answer (score -1):

Should be an index on tableA.TransactionDate. But I just translated your words to SQL and this is what I got:

```
select min(TransactionDate) as minDate
from tableA
where TransactionCode = 59
and TransactionDate >= (select max(TransactionDate) from tableB)
```